# How to make program working properly after using goto?

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, while-loop, goto

After any selection, I want to ask the user if they want to use the program again, or quit. But if y is inputted code doesn't work properly again. I tried the other solutions like clearing memory etc but I am not very experienced so I don't know what I am doing. Also sorry about my language. This is a part of my code. I have 13 different selections each of them work the same

```
    char str[100];
    int selection;
    char selection2;
    int i;
    begin:

    printf("Welcome to the Character/String Specification program\n");
    printf("Please enter whatever you want \n");
    scanf(" %s", str);

      printf("\nSelect the specification you want\n");
      printf("1) is your input a letter?\n");
      printf("2) is your input a whitespace?\n");
      printf("3) is your input a decimal digit?\n");
      printf("4) is your input a hexadecimal digit?\n");
      printf("5) is your input an upper-case letter?\n");
      printf("6) is your input a lower-case letter?\n");
      printf("7) is your input a letter or a decimal digit?\n");
      printf("8) is your input a control character?(ACSII 0..31 and 127)\n");
      printf("9) is your input a not a letter, digit, whitespace, or invisible control character?\n");
      printf("10)is your input a printable (ASCIII ' '..'~')\n");
      printf("11)is your input have a graphical representation\n");
      printf("12)Do you want to see your input as all upper characters?\n");
      printf("13)Do you want to see your input as all lower characters?\n\n");
      scanf(" %d",&selection);
      printf("\n");

      while(true)
      {
      if(selection == 1)
      {
       while(str[i])
          {
            if(isalpha(str[i]))
            {
                printf("%c is an alphabet\n",str[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c is not an alphabet\n",str[i]);
            }
            i++;
          }
          printf("Do you want to go back to the start point? (y) for yes,(n) for no\n");
          scanf(" %c",&selection2);
          if(selection2=='y')
          {
              goto begin;
          }
          else if(selection2=='n')
          {
              printf("Goodbye\n");
              break;
          }
```

Comment: While there are acceptable uses of labels and `goto`, using it instead of a loop is seldom one such use.

Comment: Also note that your code have undefined behavior, as you use indeterminate values as array indexes. And that's probably the root cause of your problem: You don't initialize (or ***re***-initialize) some of your variables. And this problem would have been simple to detect using common debugging techniques, including using an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Please take the time to learn how to debug your programs, it will make your life as a programmer much easier.

Comment: I am new to programming and I will consider your advice seriously thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using goto, I would do something like this:

```
int value = 1;
do {
   //enter your code here
   if(selection2=='n')
      {
          printf("Goodbye\n");
          value = 0;
          break;
      }
} while(value)
```

This will cause the code to run at least once and continue running based on user input.
Goto is not the best practice as it makes it harder to read.

Comment: I find goto great for breaking out of nested loops.